# Create a multidimensionnal array for retrieving opening hours out of a Laravel database

Tags: php, laravel, multidimensional-array, collections

I'm trying to make a CRUD for opening hours of shops. I've succeeded to make the "create" part.

I've made a multidimensionnal array of input, then saved it into database. Basically, the first [] go from 0 to 6 (the 7 days of a week) and the second [] take 0 or 1 for each period of a day (0 = AM, 1 = PM)

Example create input :

```
  <tr>
    <th scope="row" rowspan="2">Lundi</th>
       <td>Matin</td>
       <td><input type="time" class="form-control" name="hours[0][0][open_at]"></td>
       <td><input type="time" class="form-control" name="hours[0][0][closed_at]"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>    
    <td>Après-midi</td>
    <td><input type="time" class="form-control" name="hours[0][1][open_at]"></td>
    <td><input type="time" class="form-control" name="hours[0][1][closed_at]"></td>
   </tr>
```

Example create table :

```
id  shop_id day period  open_at closed_at   created_at  updated_at
29  1   0   0   08:00:00    11:30:00    2018-06-21 15:23:44     2018-06-21 15:23:44
30  1   0   1   12:00:00    14:00:00    2018-06-21 15:23:44     2018-06-21 15:23:44
31  1   1   0   09:00:00    12:00:00    2018-06-21 15:23:44     2018-06-21 15:23:44
32  1   1   1   13:00:00    16:00:00    2018-06-21 15:23:44     2018-06-21 15:23:44
33  1   2   0   07:00:00    09:00:00    2018-06-21 15:23:44     2018-06-21 15:23:44
```

My problem is for doing the inverse operation : convert that database data into the same multidimensionnal array, in order to reuse those data on views and controller like

```
{{ $hours[0][1]["open_at"] }}
```

I do succeed to retrieve the good data on a array, but the first key on the array is missing, so I got

```
Undefined offset: 1
```

Here is how I retrieve the data on a multidimensionnal array :

```
    $collection = $shop->shops_hour()->get()->makeVisible(['day','period']);
    $grouped = $collection->groupBy('day')->groupBy('period');
    $hours = $grouped->toArray();

    return view('shops.edit',compact('shop','id'))->with('taxonomies', $taxonomies)->with('hours',$hours);
```

Array returned :

```
array:1 [▼
 "" => array:7 [▼
0 => array:2 [▼
  0 => array:4 [▼
    "day" => 0
    "period" => 0
    "open_at" => "08:00:00"
    "closed_at" => "11:30:00"
  ]
  1 => array:4 [▼
    "day" => 0
    "period" => 1
    "open_at" => "12:00:00"
    "closed_at" => "14:00:00"
  ]
]
```

I do 
Thank you in advance !

Comment: could you show  `shops_hour` method?

Comment: @Alihosseinshahabi     class Shops_hour extends Model
{
 protected $table = 'shops_hours';

 protected $fillable = [
        'open_at', 'closed_at',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'shop_id', 'id', 'day', 'period', 'created_at', 'updated_at',
    ];

    public function shop()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Shop');
    }    
} ?

Comment: ok. please show `makeVisible`

Comment: It's in my initial post ^^ (edited)

Answer (score 0):

i added `hours` method in`Shop` Model :

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Shop extends Model
{
    protected $table='shops';

    public $timestamps=false;

    public function hours()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Shops_hour::class);
    }
}
```

`Shops_hour` Model :

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Shops_hour extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'shops_hours';
    protected $fillable = ['open_at', 'closed_at',];
    # I commented this line
    #protected $hidden = ['shop_id', 'id', 'day', 'period', 'created_at', 'updated_at',]; 

    public function shop()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Shop::class);
    }
}
```

this is my route . for example i want to edit `shop` with `ID=1` :

```
Route::get('/test', function (Request $request) {

    $shop=\App\Shop::with('hours')->where('id',1)->first();

    return view('shops.edit',compact('shop'));
});
```

`shops.edit` View :

```
<p>shop_id={{$shop->id}}</p>
<p>shop name = {{$shop->name}}</p>

<table>
    @foreach($shop->hours as $hour)
      <tr>
        <th scope="row" >Lundi</th>
        <td>Matin</td>
        <td><input type="time" class="form-control" name="hours[{{$hour->day}}][{{$hour->period}}][open_at]" value="{{$hour->open_at}}"></td>
        <td><input type="time" class="form-control" name="hours[{{$hour->day}}][{{$hour->period}}][closed_at]" value="{{$hour->closed_at}}"></td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

result :

```html
    <p>shop_id=1</p>
    <p>shop name = shop1</p>

<table>

            
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" >Lundi</th>
            <td>Matin</td>
            <td><input type="time" class="form-control" name="hours[0][0][open_at]" value="08:00:00"></td>
            <td><input type="time" class="form-control" name="hours[0][0][closed_at]" value="11:30:00"></td>

        </tr>
            
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" >Lundi</th>
            <td>Matin</td>
            <td><input type="time" class="form-control" name="hours[0][1][open_at]" value="12:00:00"></td>
            <td><input type="time" class="form-control" name="hours[0][1][closed_at]" value="14:00:00"></td>

        </tr>
            
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" >Lundi</th>
            <td>Matin</td>
            <td><input type="time" class="form-control" name="hours[1][0][open_at]" value="09:00:00"></td>
            <td><input type="time" class="form-control" name="hours[1][0][closed_at]" value="12:00:00"></td>

        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Thank you ! That's look a better approach than mine.

However, that doesn't  fix my problem (or I don't see it).

I was trying to do a complete table for opening hours (with all the days of a week and both period for each day on that table).
I wanted to create a array in order to assign manually each value for each html tile, like "Lundi > Matin" will be specifically "hours[0][0]" and "lundi >après-midi" is "hours[0][1]".

Comment: my code return all `hours` belong to one `shop`. I don't understand what you need exactly. please explain more.

Comment: With your code, If I have duplicate/wrong data, every users are going to see it.

Answer (score 0):

I've suceeded to make my array almost like I wanted by replacing my 2 groupBy

```
$grouped = $collection->groupBy('day')->groupBy('period');
```

By a array

```
$grouped = $collection->groupBy(['day','period']);
```

However, the array give me a third [0] index, always at 0 (because I don't have duplicate data on my table(?)).

The result I want is that : A fix table that contain all of the days of a week (in french there), both period (am/pm) for each days, and the correct data associated with that given day/period combination.

That code do the job, but I think it should be better, and/or without the third unwanted [0].

```
                 <table class="table table-sm">
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Jour</th>
                            <th scope="col">Pause</th>
                            <th scope="col">Ouvert de</th>
                            <th scope="col">à</th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <th scope="row" rowspan="2">Lundi</th>
                            <td>Matin</td>
                            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="hours[0][0][open_at]" value="{{ $hours[0][0][0]['open_at'] }}"></td>
                            <td><input type="time" class="form-control" name="hours[0][0][closed_at]" value="{{ $hours[0][0][0]['closed_at'] }}"></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>    
                            <td>Après-midi</td>
                            <td><input type="time" class="form-control" name="hours[0][1][open_at]" value="{{ $hours[0][1][0]['open_at'] }}"></td>
                            <td><input type="time" class="form-control" name="hours[0][1][closed_at]" value="{{ $hours[0][1][0]['closed_at'] }}"></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <th scope="row" rowspan="2">Mardi</th>
                            <td>Matin</td>
                            <td><input type="time" class="form-control" name="hours[1][0][open_at]" value="{{ $hours[1][0][0]['open_at'] }}"></td>
                            <td><input type="time" class="form-control" name="hours[1][0][closed_at]" value="{{ $hours[1][0][0]['closed_at'] }}"></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>    
                            <td>Après-midi</td>
                            <td><input type="time" class="form-control" name="hours[1][1][open_at]" value="{{ $hours[1][1][0]['open_at'] }}"></td>
                            <td><input type="time" class="form-control" name="hours[1][1][closed_at]" value="{{ $hours[1][1][0]['closed_at'] }}"></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <th scope="row" rowspan="2">Mercredi</th>
                            <td>Matin</td>
                            <td><input type="time" class="form-control" name="hours[2][0][open_at]" value="{{ $hours[2][0][0]['open_at'] }}"></td>
                            <td><input type="time" class="form-control" name="hours[2][0][closed_at]" value="{{ $hours[2][0][0]['closed_at'] }}"></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>    
                            <td>Après-midi</td>
                            <td><input type="time" class="form-control" name="hours[2][1][open_at]" value="{{ $hours[2][1][0]['open_at'] }}"></td>
                            <td><input type="time" class="form-control" name="hours[2][1][closed_at]" value="{{ $hours[2][1][0]['closed_at'] }}"></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <th scope="row" rowspan="2">Jeudi</th>
                            <td>Matin</td>
                            <td><input type="time" class="form-control" name="hours[3][0][open_at]" value="{{ $hours[3][0][0]['open_at'] }}"></td>
                            <td><input type="time" class="form-control" name="hours[3][0][closed_at]" value="{{ $hours[3][0][0]['closed_at'] }}"></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>    
                            <td>Après-midi</td>
                            <td><input type="time" class="form-control" name="hours[3][1][open_at]" value="{{ $hours[3][1][0]['open_at'] }}"></td>
                            <td><input type="time" class="form-control" name="hours[3][1][closed_at]" value="{{ $hours[3][1][0]['closed_at'] }}"></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <th scope="row" rowspan="2">Vendredi</th>
                            <td>Matin</td>
                            <td><input type="time" class="form-control" name="hours[4][0][open_at]" value="{{ $hours[4][0][0]['open_at'] }}"></td>
                            <td><input type="time" class="form-control" name="hours[4][0][closed_at]" value="{{ $hours[4][0][0]['closed_at'] }}"></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>    
                            <td>Après-midi</td>
                            <td><input type="time" class="form-control" name="hours[4][1][open_at]" value="{{ $hours[4][1][0]['open_at'] }}"></td>
                            <td><input type="time" class="form-control" name="hours[4][1][closed_at]" value="{{ $hours[4][1][0]['closed_at'] }}"></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <th scope="row" rowspan="2">Samedi</th>
                            <td>Matin</td>
                            <td><input type="time" class="form-control" name="hours[5][0][open_at]" value="{{ $hours[5][0][0]['open_at'] }}"></td>
                            <td><input type="time" class="form-control" name="hours[5][0][closed_at]" value="{{ $hours[5][0][0]['closed_at'] }}"></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>    
                            <td>Après-midi</td>
                            <td><input type="time" class="form-control" name="hours[5][1][open_at]" value="{{ $hours[5][1][0]['open_at'] }}"></td>
                            <td><input type="time" class="form-control" name="hours[5][1][closed_at]" value="{{ $hours[5][1][0]['closed_at'] }}"></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <th scope="row" rowspan="2">Dimanche</th>
                            <td>Matin</td>
                            <td><input type="time" class="form-control" name="hours[6][0][open_at]" value="{{ $hours[6][0][0]['open_at'] }}"></td>
                            <td><input type="time" class="form-control" name="hours[6][0][closed_at]" value="{{ $hours[6][0][0]['closed_at'] }}"></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>    
                            <td>Après-midi</td>
                            <td><input type="time" class="form-control" name="hours[6][1][open_at]" value="{{ $hours[6][1][0]['open_at'] }}"></td>
                            <td><input type="time" class="form-control" name="hours[6][1][closed_at]" value="{{ $hours[6][1][0]['closed_at'] }}"></td>
                          </tr>    
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
```

Comment: @Alihosseinshahabi